# Django pagination error

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-templates, django-pagination

I have created a Django application. There is a filtering functionality in my application. The filtered data is shown in a separate page.

Now I want to give Django Pagination to the filtered list page. While doing it, I came into this error. The pagination is shown at the bottom of the page with showing the correct number of pages NEXT.

But while clicking on the 'Next Page' in paginator it redirects me to my home page (/employeeList).

I suppose it is because of an `HttpResponseRedirect (return HttpResponseRedirect('/employeeList'))` I give inside the `filter()` which is used in some cases. I will paste my filter() and the HTML for pagination.

```
def filter(request):
    val2=''
    val3=''
    newData=''
    if request.GET.has_key('choices'):
        val2=request.GET.get('choices')

    if request.GET.has_key('textField'):
        val3=request.GET.get('textField')

    if request.POST:
        val2=request.POST.get('choices')
        val3=request.POST.get('textField')
    if val2=='Designation':
        newData = EmployeeDetails.objects.filter(designation=val3)
        flag=True
    elif val2=='Name':
        newData = EmployeeDetails.objects.filter(userName__icontains=val3)
        flag=True
    elif val2=='EmployeeID':
        newData = EmployeeDetails.objects.filter(employeeID=val3)
        flag=True
    elif val2=='Project':
        newData = EmployeeDetails.objects.filter(project=val3)
        flag=True
    elif val2=='DateOfJoin':
        newData = EmployeeDetails.objects.filter(dateOfJoin=val3)
        flag=True
    else:
        return HttpResponseRedirect('/employeeList')

    if request.POST.get('sortAscendValue'):
        newData = newData.order_by('userName')
    elif request.POST.get('sortDescendValue'):
        newData = newData.order_by('-userName')
    paginator = Paginator(newData, 10)
    try:
         page = int(request.GET.get('page', '1'))
    except ValueError:
        page = 1
    try:
        contacts = paginator.page(page)
    except (EmptyPage, InvalidPage):
        contacts = paginator.page(0)

    return render_to_response('filter.html',{'newData':newData,'emp_list': contacts,'val2':val2,'val3':val3,'flag':flag,'emp_list': contacts})
```

**filter.html**

```
<div class="pagination" >
    <span class="step-links">
        {% if emp_list.has_previous %}
            <a href="?page={{ empl_list.previous_page_numbe }}">Previous</a>
        {% endif %}

        <span class="current">
            Page {{ emp_list.number }} of {{ emp_list.paginator.num_pages }}.
        </span>

        {% if emp_list.has_next %}
            <a href="?page={{ emp_list.next_page_number }}">Next</a>
        {% endif %}
    </span>
</div>
```

Comment: Are you sure your generated `Next` URL has `?choices=Something` part?

Comment: yes...i am using the same piece of code in another place , where it works fine

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try

```
{% if emp_list.has_next %}
  <a href="?page={{ emp_list.next_page_number }}&choices={{ val2 }}>Next</a>
{% endif %}
```

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like you've already correctly identified the reason that the next link is redirecting to the home page:

- The next link will be something like `?page=2`
- There is no `choices` GET variable and there are no POST variables, so `val2` will be `''` when it enters your long `if` `elif` statement.
- `else: return HttpResponseRedirect('/employeeList')` will be executed, redirecting the user to your homepage.

I don't understand when or how you would want your filter code redirecting to the homepage, but it seems there are a couple of options:

- Remove the `else: return HttpResponseRedirect('/employeeList')` and use different conditions when you want to redirect the user.
- Find a way to prevent that `else` condition from matching the next link.

For the second option, you could add the following above your `else`:

```
elif request.GET.get('page', False):
    pass
```

It's certainly not a pretty solution, but it seems like the quickest (and dirtiest) option without refactoring your code.